# Photoshop - Texture like tiny 3D bumps

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I don't even know how to describe what I'm looking for, that's why I'm showing you an image:

[image]

So how could I imitate this texture on Photoshop? I don't know how to search for it online. Anyone can help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is already solved several days ago and the questioner got exactly what he asked.But the problem itself maybe earns more.

The tiny bumps obviously are like 3D half-spheres made by letting a multi-tip tool press and stretch a sheet of thin metal foil. The outset side of the foil is painted to nearly black.

As already shown, a 2D texture image of it can be made by using the pattern stamp tool. But for higher resolution one must make the pattern from scratch:

[image]

The pattern is a 20 x 20 pixels image which is filled at first with dark grey. A circular selection is made and the selection is filled with radial gradient from white to black. The idea of the gradient is the same as what's used in numerous cases where a shaded sphere was drawn.

It looks pretty good when a 1200 x 1200 pixels area is filled:

[image]

This can be warped to look curved and it can get also some (masked) light and shadow to make the lighting to be in accordance with the warping:

[image]

This is a not so perfectly succeeded attempt to make it look cylindrical with some perspective and a tilted watching direction. The curves layer with layer mask mercifully hide the badly warped edge areas and leave only the low distortion middle area well visible.

Photoshop's warping isn't good for this much distortion. The result would be much better if the curvature was only few degrees. 180 degrees is not manageable, but the shading partially hides the poor result in this case.

Illustrator's 3D effect or a real 3D program makes it much more easily. Even wrapping it around the neck of a bottle is done in a minute (assuming the bottle is already there):

[image]

This result reveals the other weakness of the bump texture image: It's flat. Good light shows that there's no bumps at all, its like printed. The shadings of the individual bumps are the same, no matter what's the direction of the light. At the edges the bumps should cover partially each other and their tops should be seen sideways. It can look right the first 2 seconds, but it stays flat after one has got the idea it's flat.

To get something more plausible the texture should be real 3D. Here's a curved piece of real 3D texture for a comparison:

[image]

The bumps even cast shadows on other bumps. Making this is not possible in Photoshop CC. Those who have old CS6 can get quite close, but it's easy only in a real 3D program.

Answer (score 2):

You could zoom in, and crop one small square of the pattern, then do *Edit > Define Pattern*

An example, zoomed into the pixel level, then cropped

[image]

Then use it by filling an area with the pattern you have defined

For example

[image]

Add a levels adjustment layer and a mask to create shading, then a warp transform to make it curve

[image]

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very very much!

Comment: @FayeD. You're welcome.